# Why does this code cause a memory leak in IE?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I am reading an [online JavaScript tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks) in which is claimed the following code will cause memory leak in IE earlier than version 8.

```
function setHandler() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('id')
  elem.onclick = function() { /* ... */ }
}
```

The author also provided the fix to prevent the memory leak:

```
function setHandler() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('id')
  elem.onclick = function() { /* ... */ }
  elem=null;
}
```

Why does the original code cause a memory leak and how does the fix prevent it?

Comment: The article explains it: *Internet Explorer prior to version 8 was unable to clean circular references between DOM objects and JavaScript.* And answers it as well: *We assign elem = null, so the handler doesn’t reference DOM element any more. The circular link is broken.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article gives a good explanation, the problem is IE and circular references.

That means that when you do:

```
function setHandler() { 
  var elem = document.getElementById('id') // (1)
  elem.onclick = function() { /* ... */ } //(2)
}
```

the first line of the function is refencing the second, and the second is referencing the first and that causes IE to not free the memory it allocated to create the elem variable.

You are breaking the reference by explicitly removing the second reference, by "destroying" the value of elem, in the line

```
elem = null
```

so IE can free the memory

The second reference happens because there is a problem with a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), the inner function bound in the onclick has access to `elem` (it exists in the function scope), so it's "locked" there.

In other words a there are two references to elem, one created in the var statement and one is made in the onclick function, and that reference won't be released until the closure is released.

You can find more info [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448(v=vs.85).aspx) and in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708831/ie-memory-leak-from-referencing-dom-elements-in-closures)

Comment: :Did you mean the circular reference by function (1) and (2)? But if this is true,why `set elem=null` will break this?

Comment: @hguser - The nested function assigned to `onclick` has access to the `elem` variable even after the `setHandler()` function completes, so if you leave `elem` with a reference to the DOM element you get a circular reference. Setting the variable to null removes this problem.

Comment: If I didn't know about why it happened - I wouldn't understand it from this answer, because of lacking of the most important term "closure" here.

Comment: @hguser: "the first line of the function is refencing the second" --- are you sure you've specified `(1) and (2)` correct?

Comment: @zerkms nope, didn't revriew the edit correctly, fixed now :)

Comment: @Nicosunshine: but even in addition - there is nothing about closures. I'm sure it's worth mentioning how and why exactly reference appears. Because right now there is no *explicit* reference. And this would confuse newbies

Comment: `When a DOM object contains a reference to an event handling function, and when event handling function contains a reference to that DOM object, then a cyclic structure is formed`. Now, `elem` is the DOM object,it reference the event handling function by the `onclick` property,but how the event handling function reference the `elem`? Since in the example,the body of the event handling function is empty.

Comment: @zerkms Ok, I tought that would be more confusing, I suppouse I could edit one last time.
@hguser there is a problem with a clousure, the inner function binded in the onclick has access to `elem` so is "locked" in the clousure, even if the function is empty.

Comment: @zerkms I think it's more clear now...but if you think you can improve it, by all means, edit it :)